# MySQL Query : Looping statement

Tags: mysql, sql

i make a temporary table before insert :

table_temp :

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
| 1    |    A      |
| 2    |    B      |
| 3    |    C      |
+------+-----------+
```

and i make "yes" button , if i press yes button then name value in table_temp will be insert to table_name, result will be :

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
| 1    |    A      |
| 2    |    A      |
| 3    |    B      |
| 4    |    B      |
| 5    |    C      |
| 6    |    C      |
+------+-----------+
```

im confused about looping query to make it work,

thanks for any advice :)

update :

i have a scenario :

take "A" name from table_temp then insert to table_name, then delete "A" name from table_temp,

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
| 2    |    B      |
| 3    |    C      |
+------+-----------+
```

take "B" name from table_temp then insert to table_name, then delete "B" name from table_temp,

```
+------+-----------+
| id   | name      |
+------+-----------+
| 3    |    C      |
+------+-----------+
```

and looping stop if table_temp is empty,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need any loop, just two SQL statements:

```
INSERT INTO table_name( id , name )
SELECT  id, name FROM temp_table;

TRUNCATE TABLE temp_table;
```

The first statemant `insert ... select ...` inserts all rows from the temp to the table.
The second one deletes a whole content of the temp table.